# define 8-col system for tablets while desktop and mobile use default 12-col system, tablet 8 columns system on Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Boostrap grid system as it is, using the 12-col system, which is fine. My designer asked me to move the Tablet to 8-col system (100% of the width should be 8 equal columns, no gutters etc).

Is it possible? if so, what should I define?

Here is the screenshot of the grid system required. The mobile 4-cols is irrelevant, since it is very easy to use the default col system for the design. I have issue with the tablet. for example, for 4-col element is easy (use .col-6), but for 3 or 5 cols, it can't be translated to 12-col system.

[image]

Comment: @tacoshy it's _not_ "2-3 lines + media queries" if you require features such as column reversal, dynamic growth / shrinking, pushing, pulling, vertical and horizontal alignment, multiple column systems with media query support for each column system, making those column systems composable, arbitrary nesting, etc. I need those things. I also maintain my own grid system: https://github.com/larrybotha/struct-scss/tree/master/scss/core/tools/mixins/components/grid

Comment: For which you have `grow` attributes. But you can always overcomplicate an issue... If you need 100 different of grid types then it would always be better to write the grid for your need instead of loading 99 grid that you don't need.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an attempt and show your code, not just ask whether something's possible.

Comment: Why not just use plain [Bootstrap flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/)? You can implement exactly as many flex children as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not correctly doable with the default Bootstrap Grid. As you already know, the Bootrapgrid is a 12-column layout and you would need blocks with 1.5 columns width.

I would recommend the usage of a default CSS-Grid here:

```css
:root {
  --col: 4;
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 786px) {
    :root {
      --col: 8;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 1440px) {  
    :root {
      --col: 12;
    }
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--col), 1fr);
  gap: 0.5em;
}


/* for demonstration purpose only */
.container > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 1vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

If you need to support the deprecated IE and as such are required to use Flexbox then you need the following formula: `(100% - ((columns - 1) * gap-size)) / columns`

```css
:root {
  --col: 4;
  --gap: 0.5em;
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 786px) {
    :root {
      --col: 8;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 1440px) {  
    :root {
      --col: 12;
    }
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.container > div {
  width: calc((100% - ((var(--col) - 1) * var(--gap))) / var(--col));
}


/* for demonstration purpose only */
.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 1vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found a simple way. it's kind of override, but it works perfectly for my needs. Here the simple code for that, you can change the class names and the media queries widths for your needs.

```
@media (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 990px) {
    .col-8-c-1 { width: 12.5%; }
    .col-8-c-2 { width: 25%; }
    .col-8-c-3 { width: 37.5%; }
    .col-8-c-4 { width: 50%; }
    .col-8-c-5 { width: 62.5%; }
    .col-8-c-6 { width: 75%; }
    .col-8-c-7 { width: 87.5%; }
    .col-8-c-8 { width: 100%; }

    .col-8-p-0{
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

And the HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="col-12 col-8-c-6">full width, and 6 out of 8 cols on tablets<div>
```